# ASP.NET MVC 5 Set values for dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to make a DropDownList with a numeric rating from 1-5. I have a rating model and I want to apply these dropdown values to `WaitTime`, `Attentive` and `Outcome`.

Can I just set these values in the view and use the model? If so how would i go about doing this?

**My Model Class:**

```
     public class Ratings
    {
        //Rating Id (PK)
        public int Id { get; set; }


        public string UserId { get; set; }

                     //Medical Practice (FK)
                    public int MpId { get; set; }
                     public MP MP { get; set; }

        //User ratings (non-key values)

        [Required] //Adding Validation Rule
        public int WaitTime { get; set; }

        [Required] //Adding Validation Rule
        public int Attentive { get; set; }

        [Required] //Adding Validation Rule
        public int Outcome { get; set; }


    }
```

**My View**:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WaitTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WaitTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WaitTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attentive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Attentive, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Attentive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Outcome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Outcome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Outcome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add a `SelectList` property to your model and populate it with 5 `SelectListItem` objects, the use `@Html.DropDowListFor()` in the view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead of EditorFor for each field:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Outcome, new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 5)))
```

Comment: Thanks @ranquild! This was simple and easy. worked like a charm

Comment: Or use the following syntax for Create/Edit views (does anybody know if it is possible to let it use the syntax from the validation?): <input asp-for="PersonalRating" class="form-control" type="range" min="1" max="10" />

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working fiddle - **https://dotnetfiddle.net/daB2DI**

In short, lets say your model is -

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    [Required] //Adding Validation Rule
    public int WaitTime { get; set; }

    [Required] //Adding Validation Rule
    public int Attentive { get; set; }

    [Required] //Adding Validation Rule
    public int Outcome { get; set; }
}
```

And your controller actions are -

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new SampleViewModel());
}


[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostData(SampleViewModel model)
{               
    return Json(model);
}
```

Your Get CSHTML should be -

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetData";
}

<h2>GetData</h2>
@{
    var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        var selectlistItem = new SelectListItem();
        var code = 0;
        selectlistItem.Text = (code + i).ToString();
        selectlistItem.Value = (code + i).ToString();
        items.Add(selectlistItem);
    }
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostData","Home")) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SampleViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WaitTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.WaitTime, items, "--Select--", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WaitTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attentive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Attentive, items, "--Select--", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Attentive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Outcome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Outcome, items, "--Select--", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Outcome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

When you run the code, you should see page like below -

[image]

And when you select some values and click on create, you should get those values in `PostData` action.

Answer (score 0):

try to adapt this to your project
in your controller:

```
    ViewBag.ParentID = new SelectList(departmentsQuery, "NewsMID", "Title", selectedDepartment);
  return View(model);
```

in your view put this

```
  @Html.DropDownList("ParentID")
```